# First order logic-formalization

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

The domain is the set of the whole numbers.

The statement is:

Every whole number is divisible by 1 and itself.

Well, let be $ Div(x,y) (x$  divides $y) $

$(\forall x)(Div(x,x) \land(Div(1,x))$ I think that my solution is missing something.

Comment: Doesn't look like there's anything majorly wrong here. Perhaps http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4700/2011fa/lectures/16_FirstOrderLogic.pdf may be able to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your solution seems fine. It reads: "For all x, x divides x and 1 divides x" or, more accurately, given the domain, "for every whole number x, x divides x and 1 divides x".

Comment: and what will be a negation of it?I'm looking for a negation in which only the atomic formulas can be negated.

Comment: The negation reads, "there exists an $x$ such that either $x$ does not divide $x$ or $1$ does not divide $x$ (or both)".

Comment: A negation is $\exists x(\lnot \operatorname{Div}(x, x) \lor \lnot \operatorname{Div}(1, x))$.

Comment: $(\exists x)((\lnot Div(x,x)) \lor (\lnot Div(1,x))$

Comment: Are my brackets at the correct place?